# c++ what design will help avoid multiple inheritance when using listeners

Tags: c++

I have larger project where many smaller classes listen to some data and in certain instances notify other classes. So i have classes like

```
class Calc {}

class Spotter {}

class Updater {}

....
```

and some other classes that listen to them

```
class Listener_1 {}

class Listener_2 {}
```

And the project ended up with many interfaces

```
class ICalcListener {
    virtual void onCalcCall( ... ) {}

class ISpotterListener {
    virtual void on SpotterCall( ... ) {}

....
```

And the listeners are not inheriting all the listeners and overwrite the callback where they need to react.

```
class Listener_1 : public ICalcListener, public ISpotterListener, ... {
    virtual void onCalcCall( ... ) { doThis(); }
}
```

The design is functioning, but I am wondering if there is a better way to deal with this than Interfacing and inheriting myself to the maximum here. Mostly all I need is to register a callback.

EDIT:
I was poking round more and and it seems like the alternative to using interfaces is using ( I am using c11 ) 
1.) delegate
2.) std::function
3.) lambda function

If performance matters, but simplicity is also appreciated, what is the best way to go?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Multiple interface inheritance is not that bad. It is data inheritance which poses many problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple inheritance from several abstract classes with methods only is not that bad, and it works. I agree it produces a lot of "junky" code to support all the types of notifications you have.

Basically, having `IXXXNotify` abstract class for every event is more Java style.

I don't know exactly what your project is and how it does things, but you could try looking for these alternatives:

1. Stick to `INotify` abstract classes, but make it more generic, so they will have only one argument like `Event` which will carry on all required information including event type. This will reduce amount of interface classes but will introduce additional headache with `switch` statements on event types. This approach breaks "OOPness" of your code a bit.
2. Make a generic event/message bus, where again you'll have generic `Event` parameters and objects which interested in particular events can subscribe to them. Take a look at visitor or observer pattern and think of them in more generic way.
3. Use `std::function` as your "event handler". Drawback here is that you can only assign one handler to any given event. You can overcome this by adding a layer on top of `std::function`.
4. Take a look at existing libraries which already handle this, like Qt or boost.

Comment: thanks, that is a nice overview. Libraries are not an option as I cant use them, but the others look interesting. this here seems a good reference for anyone to read up on patterns and designs. https://sourcemaking.com/